# Embed Audio, Video in Python GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, video, audio, video-streaming

I am working on a project that requires me to display some live video feeds from networked cameras and play some unrelated streamed OR stored audio files as well.

All the filepaths are stored in a MySQL database (although I could use something other than MySQL if that'll make things easier).

My question is this: what Python GUI libraries can I take advantage of, in order to display the video and play the audio?

I also need to display some other frames with some text, etc in them.

Can anyone please suggest a good flexible GUI library that I can use?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module `Phonon` from [`PyQt`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download)