# Python get Audio/Video frames separately from video file

Tags: python, opencv, audio, video, ffmpeg

**What i'm trying to do:**

Hi!

I'm trying to store the Video and Audio information from a video file. I would like to store video frames and audio frames separately in different variables.

My intention is to manage video/files and do some actions with the audio and video frame list, but to do what I'm plannign to do I need to store this audio/video frames separately. I've read a lot of questions in StackOverflow about python and audio/video managing.

Most people recommend to use `OpenCV` or `ffmpeg` to manage videos. I saw some scripts using these libraries to get video(only video) frames, but none of them are getting audio, most of them are just getting video frames and save them as RGB images. I also check some scripts where people get audio frames from a mp3 file, but I'm not sure if you can do that in a video file

Most important thing to me is to know the best way to manage video and audio separately. I'm not looking for people to do my code, just asking to point me in a good direction.

One of the things I'm trying to do is to send this information via socket, but as I said I need the audio and video frames to be in separated variables (yes, i'm wondering about an stream app, but that's not the only thing I'm trying to do)

I know I should give more information, and maybe show some code, but I don't have any concret code I tried some things, but I've never been capable to separate audio and video. I know that each format has his own encryption, and at the end I decided to use "mp4" as video format but I don't know neither if this is the best format for what I'm trying to do.

**Resume:**

Is openCV the best way to manage video and audio separately ?

Wich is the easiest way to separate video and audio frames ? Is it possible ?

Wich is the best documentation I should read to learn about video/audio management ?

I would like to do the things with my own code, and use in the less way possible openCV or other libraries.

My "basic" idea is to get a "list" of audio and video frames, and then I would like to do some operations, but right now I can't find the best way for me to manage a vide using python. I even wonder if could be possible to manage a video as raw data

**I need to know wich is the best library to manage videos using python, for me the best library, will be the one that allows me to manage the videos more "freely"**

**I've already checked:**

I've read too many questions on this theme, the most recent are :

[How to extract audio from video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216450/how-to-extract-audio-from-a-video-file-using-python)

[Split audio video separately from given video using MLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940553/how-to-split-audio-and-video-separately-from-a-given-video-file-using-mlt)

[Embed audio video in python gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344927/embed-audio-video-in-python-gui)

Comment: opencv can't help you at all with audio, all but the video signal gets discarded way before you can put your hand on it.

Comment: Thanks for your information, I don't care if I have to use openCV to manage video frame and other library like ffmpeg to manage the audio, where is the best place to inform myself about this in python?